# PagerDefault only returns 2 lines

Tags: 7

So I am trying to build a sortable paginated table.  So far I have failed at both.

For some reason, in this state it will only return 2 lines on page one, 10 on page two, and 2 again on page three.

Here is my code:

```
function vendor_open_orders() {
  global $user;
  $header = array(
    array('data' => t('Order ID')),
    array('data' => t('Customer')),
    // other header stuff
  );
  $query = db_select('uc_orders', 'o')
        ->fields('o', array('order_id'))
        ->distinct()
        ->condition('n.uid', $user->uid)
        ->condition('o.order_status', array('pending', 'payment_received'))
        ->orderBy('o.order_id', 'ASC')
        ->extend('PagerDefault');
  $query->join('uc_order_products', 'op', 'o.order_id = op.order_id');
  $query->join('node', 'n', 'op.nid = n.nid');
  //$query = $query->extend('TableSort');
  //$query->limit(5);
  $exquery = $query->execute();
  foreach ($exquery as $result) {
    //$rows, etc  
  }
```

...

```
  $build['pager_table'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#rows' => $rows,
    '#empty' => t('There are no open orders to display.'),
  );
  $build['pager_pager'] = array('#theme' => 'pager'); 
  return $build; 
}
```

Comment: I can't find any issues with the posted code. Try `print count($rows)` and see what you get.

Comment: good idea.  `dpm($rows)` returns an array of just the two rows thats are being displayed.

Comment: what happen if you try to comment out the join statements!! also try to add `limit(10)` after `extend` like this `->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(10);`

Comment: The limit statements are interesting. If I do `limit(10)` the results are the same.  However, `limit(50)` returns one big list on one page with no page buttons.

Comment: try to write the query in mysql command line or phpmyadmin and see if you will get the same result with limit 10

Comment: not that it matters but I usually do like:
  `$q = db_select("survey", 's')->extend('TableSort')->orderByHeader($header);`
... when using Extenders and then add fields, conditions, whatever to the query.

Comment: I think I discovered my issue.  I have an if statement after the pager so only certain results from the pager are coming through from the if statement to be displayed on the table.